# Popping up the folder when clicking "Show in Folder"

Tags: nautilus, files

Using Ubuntu 13.04, whenever I downloaded something using Google Chrome, I can click on the downloaded file, and click "Show in Folder". Currently it does not also pop up the window (nautilus) that shows the file, nor does it highlight the file in the "just-opened" folder.

EDIT: The same also happens in a similar situation using Dropbox find in folder.

Are there settings to get this done which I can't find?

Comment: Can you start Chrome from the command line and see if any error appears there?

Comment: It opens: "Created new window in existing browser sessions".

Comment: Maybe someone could put a bounty onto the question?

Comment: We normally put bounty on a question that is really difficult, and you haven't tried too much yet. Is your call at the end if you want to start a bounty yourself. But, when you click "Show in Folder" what message appear in the command line?

Comment: @Braiam How do I catch that information from my browser in the command line?

Comment: Open the terminal, then type `chrome` and hit enter. When you  click "Show in folder" copy all the content that appears there, edit your question and add the information.

Comment: Chrome itself does not work btw, google-chrome does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Focus Prevention Level** of compiz prevents active windows from getting on top.

You'll need to turn **Focus Prevention** Off. To do that follow instructions below

Install **CompizConfig Settings Manager**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then **run** CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Go to -> **General** > **General Options** > **Focus & Raise Behaviour** -> You will find: **"Focus Prevention Level"** set it to **"Off"**